# Address of getCalledValue vs getCalledFunction LLVM

Tags: function, llvm, static-analysis

I'm trying to get the address of the called operand in a direct function call. I found two plausible ways of doing so, but to my surprise, they're not equivalent.

```
if (const auto call = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&inst)) {
    Addr calledAddr;
   
    const auto called = call->getCalledValue();
  
    // Get address of called value
    ss << called;
    ss >> std::hex >> calledAddr;
  
    // If it's a direct call
    if (const auto f = call->getCalledFunction()) {
        Addr funAddr;
 
        ss << cast<llvm::Value>(f);
        ss >> std::hex >> funAddr;
  
        // This assertion fails!
        assert (calledAddr == funAddr);
        ...
```

Why does the address of the called value differ from the address of the function cast to a value? I'm using llvm-10.0.0.

Comment: Perhaps one of the two involves [a cast?](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#a1f469b1f703519ae25ce564c8704310f)

Comment: Is there any reason to recover the address of the function through a stream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in the way you're recovering the address of your pointers (through what I assume is a `std::stringstream`).

Consider these examples: https://godbolt.org/z/h5cbzco93 vs https://godbolt.org/z/rh18PjrsM .

If you compare the addresses direclty your code should have worked:

```cpp
if (const CallInst* call = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&inst)) {
    const Value* called = call->getCalledValue();
  
    if (const Function* f = call->getCalledFunction()) {
        // compare direclty the address pointed by called and by f
        assert (called == f);
        ...
```

Furthermore, if you check the implementation of `CallBase::getCalledValue` and `CallBase::getCalledFunction` you'll see that they fall-back to the same method call. The only difference is `dyn_cast_or_null` that will return `null` unless the called operand is a `Function`.

```cpp
Value *getCalledValue() const { return getCalledOperand(); }
...
Function *getCalledFunction() const {
  return dyn_cast_or_null<Function>(getCalledOperand());
}
```